# Dynamic route not working on assets in production

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Got a route like that :

`GET      /assets/*file                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

When i add some images in public/images/pictures/ I would like to access them with this url `http://localhost:9000/assets/images/pictures/test.jpg`

It works when the server is in dev mode but in production I have to restart it every time I add an image...

How I can bypass that ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James mentioned, Play's static asset controller pulls files out of the class path. Also you can define a class path which is outside your application.

You can do this by defining the following lines in your Build file.

```
val assetDir = sys.props.get("java.io.tmpdir").get + "/outside-cp"

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  unmanagedClasspath in Runtime += file(assetDir),
  unmanagedClasspath in Compile += file(assetDir),
  unmanagedClasspath in Test += file(assetDir)
```

)

Now create the following directory:

```
/tmp/outside-cp/assets
```

As last, create a route for your outside assets:

```
GET /outside/*file   controllers.Assets.at(path="/assets", file)
```

Start your application and place a file in the assets directory. Now you can access the file over the following URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/outside/your-placed.file
```

---

**Note:** You cannot use the assets directory directly as class path, because Play's asset controller prefixes the given file automatically with the path. And defining an empty path doesn't work.

If you run `play stage` to package your application, then you must change your start script to add the class path to your application.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will write my own controller. I don't need to have an assets folder outside of the application.

Answer (score 3):

Play's static asset controller pulls files out of the classpath and isn't intended for dynamic usage.  If you need to work with dynamic assets then you will need to write your own controller to handle this.